# FreeRTOS queue vs semaphore

Tags: c, queue, semaphore, multitasking, freertos

I am learning about the FreeRTOS and would like to understand more about the queues and semaphores and when it is better to use one or another.

For example, I have multiple tasks trying to talk to my I2C gpio expander (toggling pins ON and OFF).

For this to work properly, I have decided to implement a semaphore. When the I2C communication is already in progress, the semaphore is taken and given only when the I2C communication is fully complete. The example function :

```
void write_led1_state(bool state,bool current_state){
    if(state != current_state){
        if(xSemaphoreTake(i2c_mutex,1000)==pdTRUE){     
            i2c_expander(led1,state);
            xSemaphoreGive(i2c_mutex);
        }
        else{
            printf("semaphore is busy write FAN state \n");
        }
    }
}


void write_led2_state(bool state,bool current_state){
    if(state != current_state){
        if(xSemaphoreTake(i2c_mutex,1000)==pdTRUE){     
            i2c_expander(led2,state);
            xSemaphoreGive(i2c_mutex);
        }
        else{
            printf("semaphore is busy write FAN state \n");
        }
    }
}
```

Lets imagine a scenario where I have 2 freertos tasks running. One task is trying to write_led1_state and the other is trying to write_led2_state at the same time. The potential issue would be that one of those functions will fail due to the semaphore being taken by another task. How to ensure that once the function is called, even though the semaphore is not free at this particular moment but the led will still be set once the semaphore frees.?

For this particular example, is it better to implement a queue instead? For example, write_led1_state and write_led2_state would both write a value to the queue. For example value = 1 would correspond that led1 needs to be turned ON and value = 2 would mean that the led2 needs turning ON. This way, both functions can be executed at once and the queue handler task will have to ensure that the required leds are turned ON based on the value received.

These are 2 different approaches I can think of. Could someone suggest me which one is more appropriate?

UPDATE
Method 2 (Using queues)

From what I understand, the solution using the queues could look something like(Keep in mind that this is just a pseudo code)

```
// the below task will be created when we initialise the i2c interface. This task will be running in the background and continuously waiting for the messages

void I2C_queue_handler(void *parameters) {
  uint8_t instruction;
  while (1) {
  if (xQueueReceive(i2c_queue, (void *)&instruction, 0) == pdTRUE) {
      // something has been detected on queue. Determine what we need to do based on instruction value
      if(instruction == 0 ){
         i2c_expander(led1,1); // this toggles led2
      }
      else if(instruction == 1){
        i2c_expander(led2,1) // this toggles led1
       }
      
    } 
  }
}
```

And then my 2 functions from above can be modified instead of using a semaphore use a queue instead:

```
void write_led1_state(bool state,bool current_state){
    if(state != current_state){
         uint8_t instruction;
         instruction = 0;
         xQueueSend(i2c_queue, (void *)&instruction , 10);
    }
}


void write_led2_state(bool state,bool current_state){
    if(state != current_state){
         uint8_t instruction;
         instruction = 1;
         xQueueSend(i2c_queue, (void *)&instruction , 10);
    }
}
```

Is my queue implementation above correct? @Some programmer dude mentioned that I will need to have some sort of synchronization but I am not sure why is that required since my i2c_queue_handler will ensure that even when multiple tasks try to toggle the leds, onle one will happen at a time . If both tasks try to toggle an led, the first one to be sent to the queue will be written while the other will be saved to the queue and wait its turn. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If you have two parallel tasks both using a single queue, you still need some kind of synchronization. Like a semaphore (or its binary variant, the mutex).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude mutes and binary semaphores are different things.

Comment: Both will do. BTW semaphores in freeRTOS are implemented as queues

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hey thank you very much for the response. I have updated my initial question and put more details there regarding to the queue. Could you have a look and tell me if my understanding is correct?

Comment: @0___________ That is true. The only difference I am aware though is that mutex has priority inheritance. For the above application, semaphore is more correct than mutex I believe

Comment: @TheBestPlayer mutex has to be taken and released in the same task. Semaphore can be given and taken in different tasks. That's the difference.

Comment: @0___________ Thats great. Thank you very much for clarifying.